# Trouble Getting the Await Keyword to Work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

I'm struggling to get the await keyword to work in my program.  I've got a function that needs to update a global variable called newInstructions from a class.  Originally, the code calling that class was part of the main function, but it kept trying to continue the program without allowing the class code to finish.  I decided to move the code into it's own function, but that came up with an error: "The type 'Future<List>' used in the 'for' loop must implement iterable". Which makes me think that I need to use the await keyword to make sure that it finishes creating the list, but that causes an error, "The await expression can only be used in an async function".  However, all functions involved are async functions.  How do I add this keyword?

Here is the code calling the function:

```
var getBlocksList = await getInstructions();

for(var element in getBlocksList){
  add(element);
}
```

Here is the function:

```
Future<List> getInstructions() async{
  var response = TextRecognition2();
  print("response after text recognition: " + response.toString());
  var result = response.instructions;
  print("INSTRUCTIONS: " + result.toString());
  for(var i in result){
    newInstructions.add(i);
  }
  print("New instructions = " + newInstructions.toString());
  var getBlocks = GetBlocks(newInstructions);
  var getBlocksList = getBlocks.blocks;

  return (getBlocksList);
}
```

I tried adding the await keyword both to where I call the function and where I do the loop just after that, but I get the same error for both.

Comment: can you tell us what you're trying to do in the first place, and the problem that leads you to think that using await keyword is the solution

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of words from a picture in one class and then update a global variable to be that list of words, which would be used in several other classes.  I can tell that it's moving on from the instructions because I've been using print statements to determine what it's doing and it can create the list, but it does so after running other functions which rely on those words.